# How to change selected value of select in generated column based on another column value changes

Tags: java, select, listener, vaadin

in a table, there are two columns and each one has a drop down list.

```
final Table archivesTable = new Table();
archivesTable.setTableFieldFactory(new TableFieldFactory() {
    @Override
    public Field createField(Container container, Object itemId,
                             Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {
        Select sel = new Select();
        try (SSEConnector c = CisApplication
                              .generateSseConnector((SseConnection) sseSetupSelect
                              .getValue())) {
            for (String s : c.getListOfArchives())
                sel.addItem(s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("yes 2");
        return sel;
    }
});

archivesTable.addGeneratedColumn("reportName",
    new Table.ColumnGenerator() {
        @Override
        public Object generateCell(Table source, final Object itemId, Object columnId) {
            reportSelect = new Select();
            try (SSEConnector c = CisApplication
                                  .generateSseConnector((SseConnection) sseSetupSelect
                                  .getValue())) {
                for (String s : c.getListOfArchives())
                    reportSelect.addItem(s);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("yes 3");
            return reportSelect;
        }
    }
);
```

As we can see, I want any value change from the 1st "Select" in the 1st column in the table to affect the value in the 2nd "Select" in the 2nd column in the table. How?

Answer (score 0):

Generated columns do not affect vaadin table's underlying data container. They are generated on fly and no property is created for them. So, there's no obvious way to access them directly.

Ugly way to achieve this behaviour is to pregenerate all of the controls for both columns and bind them together. Store them in the map binding to `itemId`:

```
Collection itemIds = archivesTable.getItemIds();
final HashMap<Object,Select> firstColumnSelects = new HashMap<Object, Select>();
final HashMap<Object,Select> secondColumnSelects = new HashMap<Object, Select>();
for(Object itemId : itemIds) {
    final Select secondColumnSelect = new Select();
    //initialize select for the second column
    secondColumnSelect.setImmediate(true);
    Select firstColumnSelect = new Select();
    //initialize select for the first column
    firstColumnSelect.addListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        //setting value to the list in second column
        secondColumnSelect.setValue(event.getProperty().getValue());
    }
    });
    firstColumnSelect.setImmediate(true);
    firstColumnSelects.put(itemId, firstColumnSelect);
    secondColumnSelects.put(itemId, secondColumnSelect);
}
```

Then instead of generating controls on the fly just return pre-generated lists:

```
//...
@Override
public Field createField(Container container, final Object itemId, Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {
    return firstColumnSelects.get(itemId);
}
//...
@Override
public Object generateCell(Table source, final Object itemId, Object columnId) {
    return secondColumnSelects.get(itemId);
}
```

Cleaner approach is not to use generated column at all. Generated columns are not meant to be heavily involved in data operations. Instead you can just create a separate class to represent table record and implement all of the interactions there:

```
public class TableDisplayBean {
    private Select firstSelect;
    private Select secondSelect;

    public TableDisplayBean() {
        //initialization of controls, value change handling goes here
    }

    public Select getFirstColumn() {
        return firstSelect;
    }
    public Select getSecondColumn() {
        return secondSelect;
    }
}
```

All that's left is to use [BeanItemContainer](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/BeanItemContainer.html) to bind a collection of beans to table.